# dynamic Page control in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CI project, I would like to use a full dynamic page control. So, I’ve two controller methods, which load the php files. The model control’s queries are based on url segments. All page output generated automatically in the views php file depending on url and results of database, except index.php file.

Is this a right way?

**Controller**

```
public function index()
 {
  $data['title'] = "Index";
  $data['nav'] = $this->content_model->get_index_nav(); //TODO

  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/nav', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/nav_pict', $data);
  $this->load->view('pages/aktualis', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
 }
 public function view($page)
 {
  $page = 'content';

  $this->load->helper('text');
  $this->load->helper('url'); 

  $page = lcfirst(convert_accented_characters(urldecode($page)));

  if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
  {
   show_404();
  }

  $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
  $data['nav'] = $this->content_model->get_nav();
  $data['content'] = $this->content_model->get_content();

  if(empty($data['content']))
  {
   show_404();
  }

  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/nav', $data);
  $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
 }
```

**Model (Each menu has a content in database. When create a new submenu you must be add content)**

```
public function get_content()
 {
   $this->db->select('content.*, mainmenu.label');
   $this->db->from('content');
   $this->db->join('mainmenu', 'mainmenu.id = content.katId', 'left');
   $this->db->where('mainmenu.label', mysql_escape_string(urldecode(end($this->uri->segments))));

   $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query->result_array();

 }
```

**Routing**

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['/:any/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['Index'] = 'pages/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
```

Comment: How does this relate to blob images? Also, you have a hard-coded $page = "content", which I am confident is not intended to be there...

Comment: Also, how does this relate to mysqli? I only see a mysql-call, there is nothing related to mysqli. The mysql-call shouldn't even be there: `$this->db->where()` will do the escaping for you.

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working? What was expected? How it differ from expected?

Comment: He's asking for input if he's using CodeIgniter properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using CodeIgniter just fine, there's no need for any structure modification.